# spring boot 3 data jpa generate count_big instead of count

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot-3

I have following criteria method.

```
@Autowired
EntityManager entityManager;
public Long execCountQuery() {
    final CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Long> criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(Long.class);
    final Root<Order> companyRoot = criteriaQuery.from(Order.class);
    criteriaQuery.select(criteriaBuilder.count(companyRoot));
    return entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery).getSingleResult();
}
```

Unfortunately spring boot 3.2.1 generate count_big(does not exists) instead of count for H2 database. But spring boot 2.7.18 generate count. Is there any way to force to generate count instead of count_big?

Comment: Spring doesn't generate anything, JPA does. In this case Hibernate, what is generated depends on the dialect and detected database. Are you forcing an older version of H2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the same problem after upgrading Spring Boot from 2.7 to 3.2. I also got exception `InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement Function "COUNT_BIG" not found` upon calling `count()`.

Hibernate logs were showing this:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count_big(*) 
    from
        ........
```

Then I set dialect like below and `count_big()` was changed to `count()`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

Logs are showing this now:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(*) 
            ........
```

Comment: Yes.. I also fixed same way.